# Testing ArXiv compilation pipeline before submitting

Tags: arxiv

I have a paper in PDFLaTeX that I want to submit to ArXiv, but I've read in the submission guidelines that there is a 24 hour timeframe to fix errors on the first upload if they don't render correctly.

I want to avoid any preventable problems beforehand, and I would like to reproduce the compilation of PDFLaTeX documents that ArXiv does as much as possible before submitting

My pdflatex distribution is:

> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)

My files consist of the following:

1. a `.tex` file
2. a `.bbl` file obtained from a `.bib` file
3. some included graphics as PDF

What would be the closest to the command lines that ArXiv server would attempt to perform on files? I've been browsing the ArXiv guidelines for submission, but they do not go over details of reproducing the commands.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The arXiv uses [TeXlive 2011](https://arxiv.org/help/faq/texlive) and is in the process of upgrading to the 2015 version.  This shouldn't really matter much unless you are using a package which was only made available after TeXlive 2011 so most likely, if it compiles fine on your computer, it should work fine on the arXiv.

When you begin a submission, they give you a few days to add the relevant files and fill in all the required information.  During that time, you can make as many changes as you want.

It is only after you click the final *Submit* that it gets sent into the list for the next day's mailing list.  After you have submitted the paper, you can make further changes to the paper until the [deadline](http://arxiv.org/localtime) (though note that this modifies the submission time).  Once the deadline has been reached, you can no longer modify your initial submission and further changes will start incrementing the version number of the paper.

Comment: Now (NEWS 2017-02-09:) [it seems it is used TeXLive 2016](https://arxiv.org/help/faq/mistakes)...